# PlaylistItems: list Returns playlistNotFound

Tags: curl, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

When accessing a YouTube Music playlist, the API returns 404. I believe this to be a bug, because the playlist returns in Google's API Explorer. Can someone please look into this?

Example Pop Hotlist Playlist:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=RDCLAK5uy_kmPRjHDECIcuVwnKsx2Ng7fyNgFKWNJFs&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Example curl command for above playlist:

```
curl -i -G -d "part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=RDCLAK5uy_kmPRjHDECIcuVwnKsx2Ng7fyNgFKWNJFs&key={YOUR_API_KEY}" https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems
```

Returns:

```
u'error': {u'code': 404,
            u'errors': [{u'domain': u'youtube.playlistItem',
                         u'location': u'playlistId',
                         u'locationType': u'parameter',
                         u'message': u'The playlist identified with the requests <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.',
                         u'reason': u'playlistNotFound'}],
            u'message': u'The playlist identified with the requests <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.'}}
```

Comment: Could you provide the sample code?

Comment: @abielita I have added a sample curl command which returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the example they give [Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&maxResults=25&playlistId=PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE&_h=1&) using the play list id they gave PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE I was also able to do it with one of my own play lists.

```
curl -i -G -d "part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=25&playlistId=PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE&key=AIzaSyCOEeKl4YlWZ_6s-t_9Ru20S8YGAGKj1" https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems
```

**Your Play list id**

I find the error message `playlistNotFound` very descriptive here. When i try to use your play list id RDCLAK5uy_kmPRjHDECIcuVwnKsx2Ng7fyNgFKWNJFs I get

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.playlistItem",
    "reason": "playlistNotFound",
    "message": "The playlist identified with the requests <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "playlistId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "The playlist identified with the requests <code>playlistId</code> parameter cannot be found."
 }
}
```

because thats not a valid play list id. I suggest that you check again and ensure that you have copied your play list id correctly

Comment: The [explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&maxResults=25&playlistId=RDCLAK5uy_kmPRjHDECIcuVwnKsx2Ng7fyNgFKWNJFs&_h=1&) did not give me `playlistNotFound` though; it returned 200, so it is a valid playlist. Can you please revisit this?

Also, here is [the playlist on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDCLAK5uy_kKJT8tb4eLbs10ZCCNcBbDmVORfpPoa-A) to prove it is a valid playlist.

Comment: Look at the full error message you posted it is returning playlistNotFound

Comment: Yes, I know. That is the problem. It is a valid playlist so the API should **not** return `playlistNotFound`. Both the [explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&maxResults=25&playlistId=RDCLAK5uy_kmPRjHDECIcuVwnKsx2Ng7fyNgFKWNJFs&_h=1&) as well as [the playlist on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=RDCLAK5uy_kKJT8tb4eLbs10ZCCNcBbDmVORfpPoa-A) proves it is a valid playlist. Can you please file a bug or fix YouTube Radio Playlists not being accessible from the API?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue and I couldn't figure out why other playlists were working but it wasn't working for playlists I just created.
Turns out it was because those **new playlists were private!**

So make sure to confirm that the playlists you're trying to fetch is set to **public**.

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm very late but somebody is still facing issues regarding the above question. The Answer is simple there is issue with the playlistid, you can simple use other playlist id and that will work fine. Before I was using 'UCsBjURrPoezykLs9EqgamOA' this channelid and fetching playlist using this but the response was empty but successful. So, I tried using the Netflix channelid, no the playlistids and responses are successful.